# How to get error details from xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get some more information about why my request failed. It goes through the standard phases (I can see receiving headers (state 2) for a while). Then it notifies about `readyState=4, status=0` and no `statusText` set.

How can I get some more information about what happened and why?

Comment: Have you tried FireBug? Also any chance you are trying to do cross domain AJAX requests? The 0 status code is often associated to such attempts.

Comment: Show your code, what you are calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a simple website AJAX request you can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to look at all the parameters, it will not tell you what happens in code but can help you maybe figure out what is wrong with the post/get request to the server, this way maybe this is an issue with the back-end or a bug in the request uri or parameters

And in general it is a useful tool to have which is free